# How to specify compiler in makefile?

Tags: variables, compiler-construction, build, makefile

All,

I'm trying to modify a Makefile to use a embedded cross compiler instead of the PC's compiler.  The Makfile does not have the normal CC or CXX variables.  In fact, it appears that is calls another makefile with the variable '@${MAKE}'.  How can I override the '@${MAKE}' variable to force the makefile to use a diffent compliler?

Thanks In Advance,

```
# GNU Make solution makefile autogenerated by Premake
# Type "make help" for usage help

ifndef config
config=debug
endif
export config

    PROJECTS := json openjaus

.PHONY: all clean help $(PROJECTS)

all: $(PROJECTS)

json: 
@echo "==== Building json ($(config)) ===="
@${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C .build -f json.make

openjaus: json
    @echo "==== Building openjaus ($(config)) ===="
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C .build -f openjaus.make
```

I edited the Makefile based on Rob's comments, now I'm receiving the message below, not sure what to do?

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `/home/botbear/openwrt/trunk/staging_dir/toolchain-arm_v6k_gcc-linaro_uClibc-0.9.32_eabi/bin/arm-openwrt-linux-uclibcgnueabi-g++'.
```

Comment: Is the message different from what you get when you run again with the *unmodified* makefile?

Comment: The unmodified makefile runs with no errors.

Comment: We need more information. What happens if you `make json`? What if you `make openjaus`? Are the makefiles `json.make` and `openjaus.make` small enough to post?

Comment: When you modified the command, you left out the `CC=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to look inside `json.make` and `openjaus.make` to see how they build programs. If they use the conventional variables, you might be able to do something like:

```
${MAKE} CC=/usr/bin/gcc-arm CXX=/usr/bin/g++-arm --no-parent-directory ...
```

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried `make help` as the comment indicates?

Comment: yes, I tried make help. Thanks for your response, it helped. I've update my post with the new message I'm receiving.